# How to query a translatable property with API Platform and Gedmo Translatable

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, doctrine-extensions

I am using Symfony 6 + API Platform + Gedmo Translatable.

Updating / posting items is working perfectly and storing the translations correctly.
Also getting a collection in the correct language is also working.

But when I try a GET-request on the translatable field, nothing comes up.

```
GET https://localhost/api/foos?name=bar
```

What is the correct way of querying the translatable field?

I've also added the query-hints like the docs stated.

This is my code (in really short):

**App\Entity\Foo.php**

```php
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

#[Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class: FooTranslation::class)]
#[ApiResource]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: [
    'name' => 'partial',
])]
class Foo
{
  #[Gedmo\Translatable]
  private string $name = '';

  /* And all getters/setters */
}
```

**App\Entity\FooTranslation.php**

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Repository\TranslationRepository;

#[ORM\Table(name: 'foo_translations')]
#[ORM\Index(columns: ['locale', 'object_class', 'field', 'foreign_key'], name: 'setting_translations_idx')]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: TranslationRepository::class)]
class FooTranslation extends AbstractTranslation
{
    /**
     * All required columns are mapped through inherited superclass
     */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Repository\TranslationRepository` in Gedmo package and you can use  `public function findTranslations($entity)` method

Comment: Does this mean I need to create custom filter for API Platform to use a `findTranslations()` filter?